Can't understand this expression used for quantifying error during gradient checking
I was going through Andrew Ng's course 2 in 'Deep Learning specialization' wherein he talks about gradient checking using two sided distance for approximation.
My question is more about the choice of error expression in general and less about machine learning. We have two vectors $d\theta_{approx}$ and $d\theta$ wherein $d\theta_{approx}$ is the gradient vector as approximated by the two sided distance formula. and $d\theta_{}$ as calculated using the exact expressions derived using chain rule.
Note that here the approximated term is actually considered to be a more trustworthy quantity and we are using it to check the correctness of the expression written using chain rule. Andrew uses the following formula as a measure of the error:
$\frac{\lVert d\theta_{approx}- d\theta_{} \rVert_2}{\lVert d\theta_{approx} \rVert_2 + \lVert d\theta_{} \rVert_2}$
Where $\lVert .\rVert_2$ stands for euclidean norm.
I am struggling to understand the choice of the denominator.
I have seen errors in experiments being quantified with respect to the more trustworthy quantity which in this case must be the approximate term. So the denominator should, in my opinion, include only one term not the sum of both. Please correct me if I am wrong.
He does mention the reason being normalisation, but I fail to understand how.
